# Put rectangle in the center of display

Tags: qt, qml, screen

I have one Item in one of my QML components and I need to know how to set x and y to put this rectangle in the center of the Display, whatever is the parent component, I just need put this particular Item in the center every time. I have tried with Screen component but I cannot set properly. Any idea?

This is my component:

```
Component {
  id: example
  CustomItem {
    id: itemExample
  }
}
```

What I need to set in CustomItem qml file to ensure that when I instance this component WHEREVER (in wherever parent), this CustomItem appears in on the center of display and on top of all other components?

EDIT: CustomItem is an Item and it not possible to use Window or ApplicationWindow.

Comment: have you tried `anchors.centerIn: parent`?

Comment: The idea provided @felix is good. You could also try with `x: Screen.width / 2` and `y: Screen.height / 2`

Comment: @Tarod Shouldn't it be `Screen.width/2 - item.width/2`? Similarly for the `height`.

Comment: @skypjack Yes! Sorry!

Comment: Show us your code; what you've tried that didn't work.

Comment: Your solutions works in some Components and in some not, depends of where is declared the component. I need that always when I instance the Item it appears in the center, but ALWAYS, not depending. Code added